# Flask-Admin default filters

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I would like to display only paid orders in my Flask-Admin model list view.

Here is models.py:

```
class Order(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
   description = db.Column(db.String)
   paid = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Here is ModelView for Flask-Admin:

```
class OrderView(ModelView):
    column_filters = ("paid")


admin.add_view(OrderView(Order, db.session))
```

Filters work fine, but I would like to make this filter default. Or better yet, do not use filters, and only show orders that are output of `Order.query.filter(Order.paid==True)` query.

Is it possible to do with Flask-Admin?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

We do this in our app by overriding ModelView.

https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py#L654

I looked through the source code a bit for Flask-Admin, and they've made the API easier to use since we last edited this code because it looks like you can just do:

```
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView, func

class PaidOrderView(ModelVew):
    def get_query(self):
      return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.paid==True)

    def get_count_query(self):
      return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.paid==True)
```

(We were overriding get_list() which is not nearly as great.)

You can then use it like:

```
admin.add_view(PaidOrderView(Order, db.session))
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you and I can take another look.

Comment: It works great, thank you very much! Although I had to change query count function to "def get_count_query(self): return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(Order.paid==True)" , otherwise it was giving an error, something about Int object not having scalar attribute :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm so glad!

Comment: @RachelSanders: Updated your answer to include user's comment, hope that's OK. Thanks for researching this, it really helped me out!

Comment: @RachelSanders Since you seem to be a flask-admin pro: just in case you know the answer, I started a bounty on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33660840). :)

Comment: For Flask mongo dev passing by, it worth mentioning that if you use Pymongo instead then you could overide your get_list function and tweak the filter argument in there.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to filter by a property of a relationship of the model... any clues?