# Flask-admin separate view for models filtered by foreign key

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have two sql-alchemy classes. One is `Quiz` and another one is `Reply`:

```
class Quiz(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  quiz_question = db.Column(db.Text)
  quiz_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  replies = db.relationship("Reply")

class Reply(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  reply_text = db.Column(db.Text)
  reply_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  reply_mark = db.Column(db.Integer)
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
  quiz_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('quiz.id'))
```

I was able to create a view for each of those models with CRUD functionality.

I want to know what is the cleanest way to create separate view with CRUD for each group of replies related to one quiz (by quiz id). So that the list of related replies will be available through `127.0.0.1/reply/<quiz_id>`.

Thank you.

**Edit:** I look for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349773/flask-admin-default-filters) but dependent on the quiz id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem that I found was to add a link for each quiz to a page with replies where the filter for the field `quiz_id` is applied.

```
class Replies_view(ModelView):
  named_filter_urls = True
  column_filters = ("quiz_id",)

class Quiz_view(ModelView):
def _question_formatter(view, context, model, name):
    return Markup(
        "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (
            flask.url_for('reply.index_view', flt1_quiz_id_equals=model.id),
            model.quiz_question
        )
    ) if model.quiz_question else ""

column_formatters = {
    'quiz_question': _question_formatter
}
```