# flask-admin: how to customize the view according to the individual user instead of the role?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

As we all know, flask-admin allows the users with same role have the same privilege. However, in my app I'd like to restrict only the user who created a query to view and edit.

For example, there are many users with the same role called **"developers"**, he/she creates a code review and wait for approval.

The pic below shows developer **Gina** can see developer **Bill's** project in the list(which is not desired). What I'd like to achieve is only Gina and the reviewers(**Wesker** and **Steve** here) can view this project in the list.

I've put the code [here](https://github.com/samoth21/ProgrammingAssignment2/tree/master/auth)
, if it's not appropriate I will remove the link. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding ModelView, you can filter results to show logged user own results:

```
def get_query(self):
  return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.user==current_user)

def get_count_query(self):
  return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.user==current_user)
```

You can find more info here:
[Flask-Admin default filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349773/flask-admin-default-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to create another user role to achieve your goal. It will help you to save your time and you can easily customize the view specifically for the particular individual or group.

Please go through this [link](https://andypi.co.uk/2015/11/27/multiple-user-roles-python-flask/)

Answer (score 0):

Having the info you provided, a solution might look like the following

1. Rewrite/extend the logic which gathers the `Project` records so that there are only records **belonging to the current user**. An example to demonstrate might looks like this:

   *pseudo-sql*

   `SELECT team, name, project_name, version, ... FROM projects where name = current_user.name`
2. Rewrite/extend the logic responsible for saving the record so that it will verify that the `current_user` **is allowed to make changes** to the given project record